# how can I get the localUri from a temporary directory using Swift / AWSAppSync

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-s3, uri, aws-appsync

I am trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket using AppSync and iOS Swift.

Where I'm presently stuck is figuring out what the localUri is?

I am using the following to create a temporary directory for the uploading file:

```
let uploadingFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
```

and I can get the URL string as follows:

```
let uploadingFileURLString = uploadingFileURL.absoluteString
```

But how can I get the URI String?  and what is the difference between URL and URI.

I need the URI (type String) for the following:

```
let s3ObjectInput = S3ObjectInput(bucket: bucket, key: key, region: region, localUri: ???, mimeType: mimeType)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between URL and URI. You can use uploadingFileURLString in your code.